# kendo treeview programmatically refresh by node with id using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I found there is way to expand a node using ID but this example is there with jQuery. I am using angularJs kendoUI and I am not getting how to achieve below with angularJs.

Please find the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PTaKs0TxyTlAo2ZhlUxS?p=preview) link

Comment: Your code sample is exactly how you'd expand a tree item, when using angular and kendo... I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey thanx Cerbrus, I need to know how to achieve this with angularJS. There is no method with expandTo using angularJS+KendoUI. I tried this on http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/angular After update of any node I want to reload the tree and keep selected the edited node and expand the subsequent parent nodes.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is the exact problem that you are having?

Comment: Please go through the below plunker and try editing it http://plnkr.co/edit/PTaKs0TxyTlAo2ZhlUxS?p=preview

Comment: @Kmeixner Please check the plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/PTaKs0TxyTlAo2ZhlUxS?p=preview

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.